# Spring cloud stream RabbitMQ - bind DLQ with an exchange using one routing key

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I am using Spring Cloud Stream version `3.0.6.RELEASE`.

I have an existing exchange called `my.queue.exchange`. My application contains one consumer, I want to create a queue called `MY_QUEUE` and bind that queue to `my.queue.exchange` exchange. Additionally, I want to republish failed messages to a DLQ called `MY_QUEUE_DLQ`.

My problem is that the dead letter queue called `MY_QUEUE_DLQ` is bound to `my.queue.exchange.dlx` exchange with two routing keys instead of one, the first one with routing key `my.queue.rkey.dlx` and the second one with routing key `MY_QUEUE`

My consumer bean:

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Dto> consumeFunction() {

    return dto -> {
       // do stuff
    };
}
```

my `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: consumeFunction
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          consumeFunction-in-0:
            consumer:
              autoBindDlq: true
              deadLetterQueueName: MY_QUEUE_DLQ
              deadLetterExchange: my.queue.exchange.dlx
              deadLetterRoutingKey: my.queue.rkey.dlx
              deadLetterExchangeType: topic
              declareExchange: false
              bindQueue: true
              queueNameGroupOnly: true
              bindingRoutingKey: 'my.queue.rkey'
      bindings:
        consumeFunction-in-0:
          destination: my.queue.exchange
          group: MY_QUEUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `republishToDlq: false` on the rabbit consumer properties.
In the `RabbitExchangeQueueProvisioner` you can see the following code (see the comment_

```
if (properties instanceof RabbitConsumerProperties
                    && ((RabbitConsumerProperties) properties).isRepublishToDlq()) {
    /*
     * Also bind with the base queue name when republishToDlq is used, which
     * does not know about partitioning
     */
    declareBinding(dlqName, new Binding(dlq.getName(), DestinationType.QUEUE,
                        dlxName, baseQueueName, arguments));
}
```

You can also get more details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_partitioned_destinations) as to why.

Also, I see you are using

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: consumeFunction
```

Please change it to

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: consumeFunction
```

as the other property is deprecated and is already removed in 3.2 version.